# Scala case class modularization

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to scala and I have a requirement to refactor / modularize my code.

My code looks like this,

```
case class dim1(col1: String,col2: Int,col3)

val dim1 = sc.textFile("s3n://dim1").map { row =>
val parts = row.split("\t")
dim1(parts(0),parts(1).toInt,parts(2)) }

case class dim2(col1: String,col2: Int)

val dim1 = sc.textFile("s3n://dim1").map { row =>
val parts = row.split("\t")
dim2(parts(0),parts(1).toInt) }

case class dim3(col1: String,col2: Int,col3: String,col4: Int)

val dim1 = sc.textFile("s3n://dim1").map { row =>
val parts = row.split("\t")
dim3(parts(0),parts(1).toInt,parts(2),parts(3).toInt) }

case class dim4(col1: String,col2: String,col3: Int)

val dim1 = sc.textFile("s3n://dim1").map { row =>
val parts = row.split("\t")
dim4(parts(0),parts(1),parts(2).toInt) }
```

This is ETL SCALA transform code that runs on Apache Spark.

Here are the steps that I have ,

1. Define case class for every dimension.
2. Read a file from S3 and map it to respective case class. I also need to change datatype if it is required.

These steps are highly repeated and I would like to write a function like this ,

```
readAndMap(datasetlocation: String,caseclassnametomap: String)
```

With this my code will become ,

```
readAndMap("s3n://dim1",dim1)
readAndMap("s3n://dim2",dim2)
readAndMap("s3n://dim3",dim3)
readAndMap("s3n://dim4",dim4)
```

Some examples / directions will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: class names should be in `CapitalizedCamelCase`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
def readAndMap[A](datasetLocation: String)(createA: List[String] => A) = {
  sc.textFile(datasetLocation).map { row => 
    createA(row.split("\t").toList) 
  }
}
```

You can call this like

```
readAndMap[dim1]("s3n://dim1"){ parts => dim1(parts(0),parts(1).toInt,parts(2)) }
readAndMap[dim2]("s3n://dim2"){ parts => dim2(parts(0),parts(1).toInt) }
readAndMap[dim3]("s3n://dim3"){ parts => dim3(parts(0),parts(1).toInt,parts(2),parts(3).toInt) }
readAndMap[dim4]("s3n://dim4"){ parts => dim4(parts(0),parts(1),parts(2).toInt) }
```

You cannot directly give case class and ask method to construct an instance, because, the arity of the case class apply methods are different to each other.

Comment: "You cannot directly give case class and ask method to construct an instance, because, the arity of the case class apply methods are different to each other." You could do it with reflection or with macros, actually. Not necessarily a good idea (though it could be), but definitely possible.